# Do I need to compile my php files?

Tags: php

Hi i'm used to programming with ASP.Net but i got just landed a project doing PHP development.. My question is this, in ASP.Net if you make changes in the code behind you have to recompile the app before uploading. Is it the same with PHP? I know it's not a compiled language but I want to know if I can make changes to  the PHP code in a single file and upload and see my changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: times have changed... there's no shame in learning as go. :))

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to recompile. So, yes, you can immediately see your changes. It reads and parses each file as it is called which makes things quite a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you don't need to recompile before uploading. Simply change the files and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an interpreted language, there is no compilation(*). So just uploading the changed code, and refreshing the browser is enough.

(*) there are compilers around to speed up execution, but that is a different matter.